# Installing node js pulsar client on ubuntu

Tags: c++, node.js, ubuntu-16.04, apache-pulsar

I am trying to install the pulsar-client for node js client on ubuntu. I get the following error:

```
fatal error: pulsar/c/message.h: No such file or directory  #include <pulsar/c/message.h>
compilation terminated.
Pulsar.target.mk:116: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/Pulsar/src/addon.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/Pulsar/src/addon.o] Error 1
```

the documentation says

> Pulsar Node.js client library is based on the C++ client library.
>   Follow the instructions for C++ library for installing the binaries
>   through RPM, Deb or Homebrew packages.
>
> (Note: you will need to install not only the pulsar-client library but
>   also the pulsar-client-dev library)

However, the instructions for installing C++ library on Ubuntu are not very clear. It is also not clear how to install pulsar-client-dev library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that C++ library must be installed. One note is please make sure the compatible C++ library is installed.
https://github.com/apache/pulsar-client-node#compatibility

To install C++ library ubuntu, here is an example which is from our Docker image build on Ubuntu based.
https://github.com/kafkaesque-io/pulsar-beam/blob/master/Dockerfile#L29

```
wget --user-agent=Mozilla -O apache-pulsar-client.deb "https://archive.apache.org/dist/pulsar/pulsar-2.4.1/DEB/apache-pulsar-client.deb"
wget --user-agent=Mozilla -O apache-pulsar-client-dev.deb "https://archive.apache.org/dist/pulsar/pulsar-2.4.1/DEB/apache-pulsar-client-dev.deb"

apt install -y ./apache-pulsar-client.deb
apt install -y ./apache-pulsar-client-dev.deb
```

Comment: Ming, Thanks a lot. 
It worked. I feel there is a need for better documentation for those of us who are illiterate in how CPP libraries are installed on Linux.